# Will an ubuntu version update, change my SSH key?

Tags: upgrade, 19.04, 20.04, lts

I have my SSH key configured with many servers, I want to update my ubuntu version from 19.04 to 20.04 without formating the pc, I am getting the pop-up to update the ubuntu version to 20.04, Will this action change my current SSH key?

I generated the key with the ssh-keygen command.

Comment: Are you really on disco/19.04?  as it's fully tested & supported path was to 19.10/eoan, and not 20.04/focal, so that would likely be your greatest issue.. If you've added packages to your system (as most people do), the testing was from 19.04 to 19.10, testing skipping releases involves no additional packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally: no. But an update can break your system. A simple power outage can be enough.

> I have my SSH key configured with many servers

If that is the case backups are mandatory so why do you consider this an issue? Restore a backup if something goes wrong.